# Winforms report generator, where is it?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting

I am doing maintenance on a winforms project, VS2013 framework 4.5

Now I got to a point where some reports need to be build, but I cannot find the report generator that comes with visual studio.
So, this might be a stupid question, but where is the report generator from visual studio ?
Its been some years since I worked with a microsoft programming tool but I believe that something called crystal reports was delivered with older versions of visual studio. What is the report generator that is delivered with visual studio these days and where to find it ?

Comment: Crystal Reports is a completely different product from a completely different company.

Comment: @itsme86, pre VS2010 Crystal Reports was shipped with Visual Studio.

Comment: I see, but what is shipped with Visual Studio now ?

Comment: I don't believe it has one now, however I believe you can still get Crystal Reports for Visual Studio from SAP.

Comment: What do you mean it has none ? A programming environment without a report generator ? I cannot believe this. There has to be something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the `ReportViewer` that comes with Visual Studio to *view* reports. You can simply draw that control on your `Form`.

For the *creation* of reports, you can add a new `Report` item to your project, which works inside the visual designer of Visual Studio. This will create a `.rdlc` file.

[image]

Crystal Reports doesn't have a bundle agreement with Microsoft any more, so they can't be found *pre-installed* any more. You can still [download](http://www.sap.com/netherlands/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-visual-studio/index.html) it though.